# How to work with ng-polymer-elements , angularjs and requirejs together?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, polymer, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use ng-polymer-elements with angular and requirejs. I did follow this instructions https://github.com/GabiAxel/ng-polymer-elements and I had not success. When I do remove the instance "ng-polymer-elements" from my requires at the "main.js" everything works correctly. Someone can help me,please? thanks.

A little issue part:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Coderup due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Coderup' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

### main.js

```
    require.config({
        paths: {
             angular: '../bower_components/angular/angular',
            'angular-animate': '../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate',
            'angular-cookies': '../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
            'angular-mocks': '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
            'angular-resource': '../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource',
            'angular-sanitize': '../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
            'angular-scenario': '../bower_components/angular-scenario/angular-scenario',
            'angular-touch': '../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch',
             bootstrap: '../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
            'ng-polymer-elements' : '../bower_components/ng-polymer-elements/ng-polymer-elements.min',
             platform : '../bower_components/platform/platform',
            'uiRouter' : '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
            jquery : '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min'
        },
        shim: {
            angular: {
                deps: ['platform'],
                exports: 'angular'
            },
            platform : {
                exports : 'platform'
            },
            jquery : {
                exports: 'jquery'
            },
            'ng-polymer-elements' : [
                'angular'
            ],
            'uiRouter': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-cookies': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-sanitize': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-resource': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-animate': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-touch': [
                'angular'
            ],
            'angular-mocks': {
                deps: [
                    'angular'
                ],
                exports: 'angular.mock'
            }
        },
        priority: [
            'angular'
        ],
        packages: [

        ]
    });

    window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';

    require([
        'angular',
        'app',
        'uiRouter',
        'ng-polymer-elements',
        'controllers/config',
        'directives/config'
    ], function(angular,app) {
        'use strict';

        /* jshint ignore:start */
        var $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
        /* jshint ignore:end */

        angular.element().ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
        });
    });
```

### app.js

```
    define(['angular', 'uiRouter' ,'ng-polymer-elements'], function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('Coderup', ['ui.router','ng-polymer-elements', 'appControllers', 'appDirectives'])
            .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                var dirView = "../views/";
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/learn");

                $stateProvider
                    .state('learn', {
                        url: "",
                        controller: 'DadController'
                    })
                    .state('route1', {
                        url: "/route1",
                        views: {
                            "container": {
                                templateUrl: dirView + "teste.html"
                            }
                        }
                    });
            });
        return app
    });
```

### The issue:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Coderup due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Coderup' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/nomod?p0=Coderup
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:80:12
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1797:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1721:38)
    at module (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1795:14)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4064:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:335:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4048:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3974:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1484:20)
    at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1505:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=Coderup&p1=Error%3A…F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1505%3A12)
```

> Guys please, help me to resolve it. You can get this project by git.

```
 git clone https://vcrzy@bitbucket.org/vcrzy/coderup.git
 npm install
 run mongod
 cd /app
 node app.js
 go http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: I don't really get the point of require at times. Anyway, you should make angular depend on jquery if you're going to use both. Is there somewhere online we can look at this? Or a plunker? Looks okay to me.

Comment: I'm just building a structure with requireJs. To do without it is easy, I want to have 2 ready architectures. One for a giant and another one for a midget, but ultimately is just for learn. I 'll put it in the cloud.I Think so my issue is a conflict with bootstrap and polymer, polymer should be loaded before him but it aren't happening. Thanks

Comment: @vcrzy Can you provide a jsFiddle for your app? The root of the error perhaps is in on of the other files

Comment: Sorry!! git clone https://vcrzy@bitbucket.org/vcrzy/coderup.git

Comment: make sure your controllers/config and directives/config depend on angular. Further, you can declare angular to depends on jquery to get the advantage of full jquery element for directives link function.

Comment: where's your index.html? you might be loading stuff wrong. check out the following demo app I wrote for angular+polymer: https://github.com/amitit/angular-base View DEMO at: http://amitit.github.io/angular-base

Comment: @amitkspi IM USING REQUIREJS. Please read and after comments.

Comment: The error says - cannot find `Coderup`, so where is it?

Comment: try browserify instead of requirejs, much easier.

Comment: Can't access your repo, don't have access

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an issue with files loading order. You need to shim your app, with all dependencies, add something along these lines to the shim section:

```
app: [
  'angular',
  'ng-polymer-elements',
  ...
  // list all other deps
]
```

The best way to troubleshoot this issue is to watch the Network tab and see the sequence of how files are being loaded, and make sure they load in the right order.